# Trying to check if string exists in a line in a text file, but it's not working

Tags: python, string, loops, file

As the title says, I'm trying to check if a string exists in txt file and printing the line. I know there's been quite a few posts on here and online, but I tried following them and nothing works. Could someone take a look at my code and see what's wrong or missing?

The code:

```
x='potato'
file=r"C:\Users\transactions.txt"

def searchpotato():
    with open(file,'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if x in line:
               print(line)
```

The ideal results would be that all lines with the word 'potato' in the .txt file will be printed out. (potato is good, potato is better than tomato, etc.) Thanks.

Comment: Oops, edited. Both of them should be the same. Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: There isn't any error, but nothing is printed out although the txt file does contain lines with 'potato' in it.

Comment: are you caling the function `searchpotato()` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I've altered your function slightly, but kept the essence of it. Try `line.lower()` instead. As mentioned, 'potato' and 'Potato' are different, but `.lower()` makes all letters in `line` lowercase.

```
x = 'potato'
file = r"C:\Users\transactions.txt"

def search_x(file, x):
    with open(file,'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj.readlines():
            if x in line.lower():
                print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code on my machine and it worked

```
x='potato'
file=r"/var/folders/ql/tt4_4thj5fdd9xrxlpmklsrwygb8j8/T/tmp.wPLDfNsi/something.txt"

def searchpotato():
    with open(file,'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if x in line.lower():
               print(line)


searchpotato()
```

The only thing I can think of is - you declared the function but didn't call it at the end.

Also - as Arild stated - using .lower() on the line is a good idea if you dont want your search case sensetive.